# Cannot insert data into database (php/mysqli) (Phpstorm 9/Wamp)

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli, wampserver

I have an issue with inserting the data that I gather from one of my forms into my database.
Each form adds data to a different table in the database(one into users and one into tasks).

I use one form for registration and I'll paste the important parts of the code below(this one is working).
This is the form part of the `Register.php` file

```
<form method="post" action="register_code.php">
<div class="FormElement">
    <input name="user_name" type="text" class="Tfield" id="user_name" required placeholder="User Name">
</div>

<div class="FormElement">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="Tfield" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div class="FormElement">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="Tfield" id="email" required placeholder="E-mail">
</div>

<div class="FormElement">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="Tfield" id="first_name" required placeholder="First Name">
</div>

<div class="FormElement">
    <input name="last_name" type="text" class="Tfield" id="last_name" required placeholder="Last Name">
</div>

<div class="FormElement">
    <input type="submit" id="Register" name="Register" value="Register" class="button">
</div>
```

This is the `register_code.php` file

```
  <?php
require "DBconnect.php";
$post = $_POST;
if(isset($post)) {
    session_start();
    $UName = $post['user_name'];
    $PW = md5($post['password']);
    $FName = $post['first_name'];
    $LName = $post['last_name'];
    $Email = $post['email'];

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, password, email, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$UName','$PW','$Email', '$FName', '$LName')");
    if($sql)
        header("Location: Registration_successful.php");
    else
        echo "Please try again to register";
}

include 'Register.php';
```

And another form I use to add data into another table(named tasks). The data I gather from this file will not insert into my database for some reason.

This is the form part of the Add_Task.php file:

```
    <form method="post" action="Add_Task_code.php">

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="TName" type="text" class="Tfield" id="TName" required placeholder="Task name">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="TDesc" type="text" class="TextField" id="TDesc" required placeholder="Task summary">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the code from the `Add_Task_code.php` file

```
  <?php
require 'DBconnect.php';

$post=$_POST;

if(isset($post))
{
    $TaskName = $post['TName'];
    $TaskDesc = $post['TDesc'];

    $sqltask="INSERT INTO tasks ('TName','TDesc') VALUES ('$TaskName','$TaskDesc')";

    if ($con->query($sqltask))
        header("Location: Tasks.php");
    else
        header("Location: Add_Task.php");
}
?>
```

The file `DBconnect.php` only contains this:

```
   <?php

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","first_app")

?>
```

The problem is that even though the code is similar in both forms only one of them is working. Every time I run the `Add_Task.php` file it redirects me to the same page (as I instructed it) since it does not add anything to the database.

I also checked the tables just in case it adds something but it does not.

Comment: Wrap off `quotes` from `table and column` name instead use `backtick`. Problem in this line `tasks ('TName','TDesc')`

Comment: Please take a look into your http server error log file. There you can read what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: Side note: your code is wide open to sql injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please set your primary_key(id) as auto increment in table tasks. if you not set it might be possible. 
and change this line

```
$sqltask="INSERT INTO tasks ('TName','TDesc') VALUES ('$TaskName','$TaskDesc')";
```

like this :

```
$sqltask="INSERT INTO tasks (TName,TDesc) VALUES ($TaskName,$TaskDesc)";
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the feedback and specially to Vasanth Kumar and jilesh for the answers. Once i removed the backticks from the 2  elements in here ('TName','TDesc') it worked. And i also used this echo "Error: " . $sqltask. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); really helpful line to figure out why it wasn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `OOP style` and `Procedural Style` in your code

You are used `Procedural Style` in your `DBconnect.php` file. And You are missing `;` in your connection file.

**DBconnect.php** file should be:

```
<?php    
   $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","first_app");    
?>
```

**register_code.php** code should be:

```
<?php
require "DBconnect.php";
$post = $_POST;
if(isset($post)) {
    session_start();
    $UName = $post['user_name'];
    $PW = md5($post['password']);
    $FName = $post['first_name'];
    $LName = $post['last_name'];
    $Email = $post['email'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (user_name, password, email, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$UName','$PW','$Email', '$FName', '$LName')");
    if($sql)
        header("Location: Registration_successful.php");
    else
        echo "Please try again to register";
}
include 'Register.php';
```

**Add_Task_code.php** file code should be:

```
<?php
require 'DBconnect.php';

$post=$_POST;

if(isset($post))
{
    $TaskName = $post['TName'];
    $TaskDesc = $post['TDesc'];

    $sqltask="INSERT INTO tasks ('TName','TDesc') VALUES ('$TaskName','$TaskDesc')";

    if (mysqli_query($con,$sqltask))
        header("Location: Tasks.php");
    else
        header("Location: Add_Task.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the below changes and see what the actual error is.then debug your code.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
   $TaskName = $post['TName'];
   $TaskDesc = $post['TDesc'];

   $sqltask="INSERT INTO tasks ('TName','TDesc') VALUES ('$TaskName','$TaskDesc')";

   if ($con->query($sqltask))
     echo "Successfully Inserted";
   else
     echo "Error: " . $sqltask. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```